# Web Services with ESB

Tags: web-services, esb

I have many webservice that they use wsdl. I want to use ESB for relation between webservices.
I don't know choose mule, is it correct or no?
I search about this problem I find wso2 esb, I don't know it's good for my work or no. I'm very confused.
I don't know how do I do?
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as well Oracle Service Bus as well.

Here are some notes i do for a coleague asking same question:

One thing to know about ESB is that there is not perfect definition for it. The scope and role may vary depending on the needs.

One of the most important things that you can do via ESB is to decouple the client from the
service providers

ESB helps to have:

● a service location transparency

● sharing of services accross the enterprise

● separate the business service from service implementation

Esb Capabilities :

**Routing**

The ability to redirect a client request to a particular service provider based on deterministic or
variable routing criteria.

Types of routing to consider:

● static or deterministic routing

● content based routing

● policy based routing

● complex rules based routing

**Message transformation**

The ability to transform the client request to the format the service provider expects it.
Most used transformations are:

Xml -> Xml

Xml -> Cobol

Object -> Xml

Xml -> Json
etc.

**Message enforcement**

The ability to enrich,enhance the message that comes as request as the service provide
requires.

Types of message enforcement:

● Date format conversion

● Data conversion (ex: transform spaces to 0)

● Rule based enhancements. (ex: if message is from x add some information to the
request)

**Protocol transformation**

The ability to accept from the consumer one type of protocol as input (ex SOAP/JMS) and
communicate to the service provider other protocol (ex: IIOP)

**Service Mapping**
The ability to translate a business service into the corresponding service implementation and
provide binding and location information

**Message Processing**

The ability to manage state and perform request management by accepting an input request
and ensuring delivery back to the client via message synchronization.
Process choreography

The ability to manage complex business processes that require the coordination of multiple
business services to fulfill a single business request.

**Service Orchestration**

The ability to manage the coordination of multiple implementation services.

**Transaction management**

The ability to provide a single unit of work for a business service request by providing a
framework for the coordination of multiple resources across multiple disparate services
(see more WS - Coordination)

**Security**

The ability to protect enterprise services from unauthorized access

ESB should provide 4A’s of security :

1. Authentication
2. Authorization
3. Auditing
4. Administration

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried with Mule and WSO2 ?

All ESB can interact with WebServices. An alternative to Mule and WSO2 would be to use [Apache-Camel](http://camel.apache.org/). They have a [nice support for Web Services](http://camel.apache.org/spring-web-services.html).

Comment: I want to configure ESB that all of my webservice in different server interact with my ESB. I don't know that I use which products for ESB. my ESB sometimes send request to another server for recieve response, and somtimes send response to client.